# Using Javascript code twice

Tags: javascript, variables

First of all I want to say that I am sorry for not using the Code sample. This is my first time asking on stackoverflow and I found it really confusing.

I have this javascript code which works perfectly, but when I try to duplicate it and change the variable names it doesn't seem to work.

**JavaScript**

```
function saveEdits() {
    var editElem = document.getElementById("edit");    
    var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;    
    localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;    
    document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Edits saved!";

}
function checkEdits() {
    if(localStorage.userEdits!=null)
        document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML=localStorage.userEdits;
}
```

the way i tried to edit(im new to javascript i have no idea what i was doing):
**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveEditsplus() {
    var editElemplus = document.getElementById("editplus");
    var userVersionplus = editElemplus.innerHTML;
    localStorageplus.userEditsplus = userVersionhtml;
}
function checkEditsplus() {
    if(localStorage.userEditsplus!=null)
    document.getElementById("editplus").innerHTML=localStorageplus.userEditplus;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can format code blocks by starting every line with four empty spaces.

Comment: Or using the `{}` button in the toolbar.

Comment: or select your code and press `ctrl +k`

Comment: What did you duplicate? Show us the piece where you changed the variable names! Also, how/when are these functions called?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what makes the **{}** button confusing?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to learn the proper markup.

Comment: define the variable `localStorage` outside of the functions

Comment: @Bergi i've added the duplicate, i use the code this way:
    <div id="edithtml" contenteditable="true">
    Type here
    </div>
    <p>&#160;</p>
    <img src="savehtml.png" height="20" width="20"     style="position:absolute; cursor:hand;"value="save my edits"      class="fade" onclick="saveEditshtml()"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code, you changed the name of `localStorage` to `localStoragePlus` - but localStorage is something provided by your browser (see .

If you change it back to `localStorage`, it might work again.

For reference, here's the part with the renamed variable:

```
function saveEditsplus() {
    var editElemplus = document.getElementById("editplus");
    var userVersionplus = editElemplus.innerHTML;
    localStorageplus.userEditsplus = userVersionhtml;
                ^^^^
}
```

<s>By the way, you're not using localStorage correctly. If you want to save something across page reloads, you need to call "set"</s> I learned that this is not true. sorry for the confusion. ([tutorial](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html))

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using properties directly instead of setter methods on `localStorage`

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for the comment. I did not know that! I corrected my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looks like you have no idea what the code is doing… [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage) is a browser api, you can't just rename it (like you can't - and didn't - change `document` or `innerHTML`).

However, there's no reason to rename any of the variables at all. By using the [`var` declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), you made them local to each of the functions, so they won't interfere with each other anyway. All you need to change are the references to the element:

```
function saveEditsplus() {
    var editElem = document.getElementById("editplus");
    var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;
    localStorage.userEditsplus = userVersion; // no …html suffix, either
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the storage reference is global, though
}
function checkEditsplus() {
    if(localStorage.userEditsplus!=null)
    document.getElementById("editplus").innerHTML=localStorage.userEditplus;
}
```

However, even better than copying the code would have been to give these [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) parameters - one for the id of the element, one for the [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) of `localStorage` that is supposed to be used.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot modify the localStorage (browser api)!

```
function saveEdits() {
    var editElem = document.getElementById("edit");    
    var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;    
    localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;    
    document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Edits saved!";

}
function checkEdits() {
    if(localStorage.userEdits!=null)
        document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits;
}
```

Comment: you can overwrity pretty much anything in JavaScript. And furthermore, in this case the use is alright. (i didn't know, either, but try in your JS REPL. It works.)